# How to check if searchform.php is being included as widget?

Tags: widgets, templates, search, sidebar

I'd like to put something like this in searchform.php:

```
<?php if($widget){ ?>
    //load serach form for sidebar...
<?php }else{ ?>
    //load different search form for page content (404 page)
<?php } ?>
```

How can I prepare `$widget` variable? Or maybe I should use another method? Like filter? Or get template part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Check if searchform is included?

The [`get_search_form()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_search_form/) function (that *should* be used) uses [`locate_template('searchform.php');`](http://queryposts.com/function/locate_template/)  to display the search form.

The later returns (as you can see from its source)

> the template filename if one is located

So if you're just wanting to catch the default way, then you should simply test

```
'searchform.php' === locate_template( 'searchform.php' ) AND print 'Search form displayed!';
```

You can maybe think of a hundred of other scenarios on how to include the search form, but you'll never catch them all.

The real problem (and I don't have a solution for that) is that this only checks the existence, not if it is included via a widget. So above is only meant to work from inside a (custom) widget.

### Display widget programmatically

If you want to display a widget (in absence of others) via PHP code in your template, then go with [`the_widget()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget) <sup>[Source link](http://queryposts.com/function/the_widget/)</sup>.

### Check your sidebars

To inspect your sidebars, you can *simply* check the `$GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars']`.

### Check your widgets

Core also has a possibility to check the registered widgets: [`wp_get_sidebars_widgets()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_sidebars_widgets/), which you can use to check for the existance of a widget.

Comment: I'm marking this as accepted answer because it contains a lot of useful information :) More than I expected to get and it helps also with other issues I'm encountering. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with `get_template_part();` - you just need searchform.php and searchform-different.php.